# Module.css is not working in React.So css can't proceed either. Please reply

Tags: css, reactjs, react-css-modules

First of all, I made a project with RCA. And I used the CSS Module.
It went well at first, but suddenly there was a problem.
[image]

As shown in the picture above, classname was assigned to the div tag, but there was a problem that could not be applied in the developer window.

[image]

It's the highlighted part in blue.
That's how I worked on the css, but it suddenly started to not work.
Please comment on how to solve it.

Comment: It won't appear in the DOM if the ruleset is empty, are you sure `.contain` has styles in it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I specified a class name, I didn't know that if there was no style, the class name could not be specified. I learned something today. Thank you again.

Comment: That's OK, glad you learned something!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 Import styles from  './header_Module.css'.
```

not this way
Import styles from  './header.Module.css'.

> ok i got it, rename your css file name . header.module.css is creating your problem .

Comment: i got your problem .check it now